# How to reload data each time link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, function, dom-events, reload

```
var switchit="show";
$('.swap_ref').click(function(){
    if(switchit=="show"){
        get_main_times();
        $('.x1').hide();
        $('.swap_ref').text("Show Main Times");
        $('.x2').show();
        switchit="hide";
    }
    else{
        $('.x2').hide();
        $('.swap_ref').text("Show Sundry Times");
        $('.x1').show();
        switchit="show";
    }
})


function get_main_times(){
        //$('.x2').html("");
        var data="agent_id="+agent_id+"&key=1";//get main_dates
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"admin_includes/get_sundry_details.php",
            data:data,
            success:function(html){

                var element;
                var split_times=html.split("^");
                var split_times_count=split_times.length-1;
                for(var a=0;a<split_times_count;a++)
                {
                    element=split_times[a].split("|");
                    day=element[0];
                    hour=element[1];

                    $('.day_holder1a').each(function(){
                    var get_day=$(this).data('day');
                    var get_time=$(this).data('time_slot');
                    if(get_day==day&&get_time==hour)
                    {
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'red').text("");
                        //$(this).data('state', '0');
                    }

                    });
                }

            }//last function
        })//end ajax

    }
```

The code above switches from one editable table to another. The problem I am having is that I need to force the ajax function to function each time the user switches from one table to the other.

There is no problem with switching between the two tables - it is just that there seems to be the need for some sort of reset on table 2 (.x2) as it just maintains the original data from when it was first loaded.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `get_main_times` in the `else` of your click function. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. That is intentional - this just shows a pre-built table (.x1) which is editable to a database. However the problem is that when this first table is edited and the user switches back to the second table, the second table does not reload via the ajax request and therefore is not updated.

Comment: Can you post the html for these tables as well (maybe in jsfiddle.net)? It's hard to see how these selectors relate without it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem - quite basic

return false;

at the end of the function causes the desired effect I am after.